# Dynamic loader missing symbol abort trap signal in Fortran runtime

Tags: xcode, macos, fortran, netcdf, intel-fortran

I am trying to run my fortran code (xytestnc.f; attached) with ifort compiler with below code

```
ifort xytestnc.f -I/Users/shewag/install_library/include -L/Users/shewag/install_library/lib -lnetcdff
```

I am getting the dynamic loader error mentioned below

```
dyld[4272]: missing symbol called
forrtl: error (76): Abort trap signal
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
libnetcdff.7.dyli  000000010DC3FF5A  for__signal_handl  Unknown     Unknown
libsystem_platfor  00007FF819372FDD  _sigtramp          Unknown     Unknown
Abort trap: 6
```

How can this problem be resolved?

I am currently using MacBook Pro with M2 chip (MacOS Sonoma).

I have a sample fortran code for preparing 2D netcdf data. For running the fortran code, I successfully installed intel fortran version "m_HPCKit_p_2022.1.0.86_offline".

Also installed other libraries in this order zlib-1.2.11, szip-2.1.1, hdf-1.10.7, netcdf-c-4.5.0, udunits-2.1.24, netcdf-fortran-4.5.1. Also using latest Xcode version.

Also have gcc, gfortran using home-brew.

Comment: Please share your code for `xytestnc.f`?

Comment: It looks like some kind of a configuration problem where something that you were able to resolve at link time isn't in the dynamic library loaded at runtime.  I'm not familiar with what there might be for diagnostic tools in non-Windows OS to debug it.  In Windows, I would recommend to use gflags to turn on loader snaps to get detailed diagnostic output from the loader; maybe there's an equivalent for dyld in Unixy operating systems.

Comment: @datawookie if the problem is what it looks like to me, having the code won't help.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to specify which symbol is unresolved, which is why I wanted to see the source code (or at least a minimal `.f` file which can be used to replicate). The question does mention that the file is attached "(xytestnc.f; attached)" but I don't see it.